# Default value is GUID in SQL Server table column

Tags: sql-server, guid

I need to add a column to an already existing table and set it to be the primary key. I use other software to add new data. Why does the column `GIANGGUID` have the value `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` ?

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Test 
   ADD [GIANGGUID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID() PRIMARY KEY;
```

Comment: What is the question???

Comment: Why the column GIANGGUID has value as 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000?

Comment: Most of the time is a bad pratice to use a GUID as a primary key in SQL Server see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938044/what-are-the-best-practices-for-using-a-guid-as-a-primary-key-specifically-rega

Comment: We'll need to know exactly how you insert the row that has the 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 GUID in it. And whether you inserted that before or after you added your default. That's not really clear from your question. (Also, if you're using a GUID as a primary key you need to be careful; there's a lot of variables to consider, but `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` may be a better choice than `NEWID()`. Even better would probably be a simple incrememnting integer, if you can manage it.)

Comment: Are you using an ORM? If so which one? Any way it looks as though your insert is inserting that value explicitly so the default never comes into it.

Comment: I think that whether your existing values get new GUIDs depends on whether the column is declared NULLable or not. If that's not explicitly declared, as in the question here, I think whether it defaults to NULLable or not depends on a few things. Looks to me like the PRIMARY KEY declaration implies that the column should be NOT NULL. Certainly if I try your code on my local SQL Server, I *do* get expected GUID values in my column for existing rows...

Comment: I see there are answers here which make general assertions which in many contexts just aren't true. A GUID is not necessarily a bad thing as a Primary Key. Yes it should be random, that is the point and yes that makes it a poor choice as a clustered key. However a sequential GUID is a nonsense. If a clustered index is important then add an INT field, make it a key, sequential and clustered. But if you need a unique unguessable key value, use a GUID (UUID for the rest of the universe).

Comment: Sequential GUIDs aren't nonsense, they are what you get if you call NEWSEQUENTIALID. And they are *still* GUIDs, that is unique, not random. There's nothing random about most GUID algorithms (there are many). Random means duplicatable. In any case, this isn't an answer. At best it's a comment. SO is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. Answers are supposed to actually answer the questions. There's a reason people with less than 50 rep can't post comments too. You need to understand how SO works first

Answer (score 36):

Several things are happening here.

If you simply add a column with a default value using this query:

```
ALTER TABLE #Test ADD [GIANGGUID] uniqueidentifier DEFAULT NEWID();
```

You will get NULL value for existing columns because NULL are allowed and newid() for newly inserted rows:

```
id  name    GIANGGUID
0   A       NULL
1   B       NULL
2   C       NULL
```

Now, if you add a new column with NOT NULL:

```
ALTER TABLE #Test ADD [GIANGGUID] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID();
```

Since the column can't be NULL, the DEFAULT constraint is used and newid() is inserted for each existing row:

```
id  name    GIANGGUID
0   A       52C70279-B3A4-4DE6-A612-F1F32875743F
1   B       3005D9BE-5389-4870-BAA9-82E658552282
2   C       E50FDD26-A8FD-43BD-A8F0-3FDA83EFF5D9
```

The same thing happens when you add a Primary Key because the PK can't be NULL and newid() will be added as well with this ALTER:

```
ALTER TABLE #Test ADD [GIANGGUID] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID()-- PRIMARY KEY;
```

- With your query, newid() will be inserted for new and existing rows.
- With the other queries above, you will either get NULL or newid().

There is no reason to end up with `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` unless something that has not been mentionned do it or transform it.

Now if we put this problem aside, you should not consider using a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER as a Primary Key. GUID are:

- not narrow
- random although Sequential GUID could be used.

If you need something random and unique such as a GUID in your table for some reasons, you can keep this column without a PK and also add an extra unique and sequential ID column (bigint with identity) as you PK.

Sample Data:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test(id int, name varchar(10));
INSERT INTO #Test(id, name) values
    (0, 'A')
    , (1, 'B')
    , (2, 'C');
```

**Edit to go around the software insertion issue...** (see [GUID of 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 causing merge index violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001362/guid-of-00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000-causing-merge-index-violation))

Rename the table:

```
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.test', 'test_data'
```

Add the new column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Test_data ADD [GIANGGUID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID() PRIMARY KEY;
```

or:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Test_data ADD [GIANGGUID] bigint identity(0, 1) PRIMARY KEY;
```

Create a view without GIANGGUID:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.test AS
    SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM dbo.test_data
```

When the software will do its insert it won't see GIANGGUID and it won't try to insert something automaticaly.

Comment: I add a column is GIANGGUID and set a primary key for it, but when I add a few rows data, the first row value is 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000  and the rows next  will can not insert because it duplicate primary key, The problem is that when I set the default value or binding is newid () or newsequentialid (), the primary key have value is 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000. default my table is no primary key

Comment: how do you insert the new row ? your code probably replace it with 000000.

Comment: I do not have permission to edit code. I just be allowed to add a column is GUID to tracking table

Comment: the code used to insert new rows probabably add the 0000. What software is used to insert rows in your table ?

Comment: I added a new field is GIANGGUID, it does not depend software to insert data because it auto generate by newid () or newsequentialid ()

Comment: yes it should but perhaps the software see this column and insert something else.... can you remove try it with ALTER TABLE #Test ADD [GIANGGUID] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL and see if you still get 00000 ?

Comment: i had try it with ALTER TABLE sde.BDTDS_28939 ADD GIANGGUID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL; and result is 000000.

Comment: i need enable change tracking for table no primary key, there are other ways to solve this problem?

Comment: is a bigint identy(0, 1) an option for your?

Comment: i had try for this, and error occur "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'BDTDS_28939'" when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF". I've set it ON is still error.

Comment: This is a problem with the sowftare try to insert everything. Perhaps you can create a new table where you will store the guid and add a trigger to the main table. Another option is to rename test to test_data, add the guid column with newid() to it and create a view called test with all test_data column except the guid. The software will not see the guid and will not try to insert it. see edit in answer

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to get the default value in SQL server, Use the below conversion value to get the `default guid`

```
select CAST( cast(0 as binary) as uniqueidentifier)
```

**Result**

```
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent a long time trying to figure this out. It appears you need the following format for a derived column to be a GUID. (DT_GUID) "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"